# Two gridview in one page sorting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two gridview in page.Both gridview contains individual update panel and both gridview have dummy header.I want sort both gridview.So i was used Jquery.One gridview sorting properly done.That same jquery i used for another gridview,But not working.My code

```
  function SortTran(cell, sortOrder) {
        var sorting = [[cell.cellIndex, sortOrder]];
        $("#<%=gvCustomer.ClientID%>").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        if (sortOrder == 0) {
            sortOrder = 1;
            cell.className = "sortDesc";
        }
        else {
            sortOrder = 0;
            cell.className = "sortAsc";
        }
        cell.setAttribute("onclick", "SortTran(this, " + sortOrder + ")");
        cell.onclick = function () { SortTran(this, sortOrder); };
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCustomer.ClientID %>").scrollTop = 0;

    }

    function SetTranDefaultSortOrder() {
        var gvHeader = document.getElementById("dummyTranHeader");
        var headers = gvHeader.getElementsByTagName("TH");
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            headers[i].setAttribute("onclick", "SortTran(this, 1)");
            headers[i].onclick = function () { SortTran(this, 1); };
            headers[i].className = "sortDesc";
        }
    }


        $.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: 'balance',
            is: function (s) {
                return false;
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return s;
            },
            type: 'number'

        });

  $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#<%=gvCustomer.ClientID%>").tablesorter({
                headers: {
                    2: {
                        sorter: 'balance'
                    }
                }
            }); 
       SetDefaultSortOrder();
   });
```

This same coding i used for another gridview,But not working properly.Why?Is no possible to sort two gridview in page?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a jquery plugin to handle the sorting?  http://tablesorter.com/docs/